# How to abbreviate a string as the width of a column grid?

Tags: gwt, string, sizeof, gxt

I'm using GWT 2.2.0 and GXT 2.2.3.

In my project, I have a grid and its columns has no fixed size and I can resize the columns. In each column I have a div that contains a string result.

I would like to abbreviate the string as the column width. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is a little too broad.  More specific questions like "how can I set the text in a cell?" or "How can I be notified when the columns change size" will be easier for us to answer with confidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [text-overflow](http://www.css3.info/preview/text-overflow/). AFAIK it does not work in firefox, but you should find solution for this browser when you search for 'text-overflow'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me to find this solution: http://ernstdehaan.blogspot.com/2008/10/ellipsis-in-all-modern-browsers.html